# Phoenix/Elixir reboot system from web

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, system-shutdown

Is it possible to reboot a system by sending a request to a web server? Here is what I've tried so far, but keep getting error `(Plug.Conn.NotSentError) a response was neither set nor sent from the connection`.

```
defmodule App.Web.SystemController do
   use App.Web, :controller

  def system(conn, %{"command" => command}) do
    "sudo shutdown -r now" |> String.to_char_list |> :os.cmd
   conn
 end
end
```

I am working on a local server on RPI, and would like to have a button in the interface that auto reboots the server. What is the proper way to shutdown the server with elixir?

I was thinking also that I can write a bash script, and just call it instead, but not sure if it's going to have any negative consequences on webserver. Any suggestions, advice appreciated!

Error I get from terminal:

```
Request: POST /api/v1/system_power/
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Plug.Conn.NotSentError) a response was neither set nor sent from the   connection
    (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:42: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.maybe_send/2
    (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:16: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
    (cowboy) /Users/user/app/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

Comment: Do you get any error logged that the command failed to run? Also, you need to return a Conn from that, you can just add `text(conn, "done")` after the `:os.cmd` line.

Comment: Hey @Dogbert, I've posted the full error I receive. I also tried to add `text(conn, "done")` which eliminated the error from console, but the command itself is not executed.

Comment: Do you get any `sudo` related error? Try doing `IO.inspect(:os.cmd('sudo shutdown -r now'))` instead. That should log the output of that command.

Comment: I think `text(conn, "done")` helped actually, and the problem is with my system that requires the sudo password in order to actually shutdown. From your command I get `'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified\n'`

Comment: Yep, @Dogbert, the problem is that it asked for sudo password that I didn't provide. I've tried other commands that don't require sudo, and it works now. Thanks a lot man!